# I was working on mongoose in Express JS. so I can face such error "student validation failed: fees: Path `fees` is required. at ValidationError"

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, backend

[Here's My Schema:[here's how I trying to Get my Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRG6W.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQHTd.png)

When I click the submit Button There is the Problem in Fees Validation that I mention Above.

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(req.body)` prints?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.